# Adding friends in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am following this post for adding users as friends in ruby on rails

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association

I am able to add users as friends via rails console but not via the actual page...this is my controller code

```
class FriendshipsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create  
    @friendship = current_user.friendships.build(:friend_id => params[:friend_id])  
    if @friendship.save  
      flash[:notice] = "Added friend."  
      redirect_to phones_index_path  
    else  
      flash[:notice] = "Unable to add friend."  
      redirect_to phones_index_path
    end  
  end 

  def show
  end
end
```

Model:
User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
has_many :contacts
has_many :phones
has_many :friendships
has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
has_many :inverse_friendships, :class_name => "Friendship", :foreign_key => "friend_id"  
has_many :inverse_friends, :through => :inverse_friendships, :source => :user  
  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :user_id
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
end
```

friends:

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :friend_id, :user_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

view:

```
<h1>Phones#index</h1>
<center>Users in the system<center><br/>
<p><% @phones.each do |variable|%>
    <% if @phn.email!= variable.email %>
    <br/><%= variable.email %> &nbsp; <%= link_to 'Add as Friend' , friendships_path(:friend_id => @user), :method => :post %>
    <%end%>
    <%end%>
<p>friends</p>
<% for user in current_user.friends %>
<p><%= user.email %></p>
<%end%>
```

my view is working correctly .. if i add friends via console and commit it, it displays in the view..
where did i go wrong here??

Comment: how are you getting `params[:friend_id]`? you should post your model and your view.

Comment: i am just displaying the firend's email id in view file

Comment: you misunderstood what view I'm asking for.  can you show the view where the user most probably selects the friend they want to add?

Comment: On this line: `<br/><%= variable.email %> &nbsp; <%= link_to 'Add as Friend' , friendships_path(:friend_id => @user), :method => :post %>`, what happens if you change `@user` to `@user.id`?  If it doesn't work, can you post a log trace.

Comment: cannot give user.id as mass accessing is prohibited in rails 3

Answer (score 0):

I was able to correct it..had wrong code in my view file.. thanks a lot jvnill....had it not been for you, I would not have checked my view file... :)

changing `friendships_path(:friend_id => @user)` 
to `friendships_path(:friend_id => variable)   did the trick`